# C multidimensional array , can't see what's wrong

Tags: c, arrays

The program needs you to enter the number of lines and columns (m and n) , enter elements into the array, then specifiy an element to be found and find it.

Once you do , print the position found at (starting with 1) , the line and column index, also specify the number of times the element was found.

The problems with my program : it prints several times bad numbers before the final printf that shows the correct location. If the location of the searched is at the start it shows nothing. I tested with printf the second for loop and saw that it only displayed the last 2 elements entered into the array.

Another problem is that i get an error anytime i try to enter a array that is bigger than [2] [2] , for example [3][3].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    int m=0,n=0,tablou[m][n],i,j,e,nr=0,poz=0;
    printf("Introduceti nr. de linii si nr. de coloane");
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    printf("Introduceti elementele in tablou\n");

    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&tablou[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Introduceti elementul pe care vreti sa-l gasiti");
    scanf("%d",&e);
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            poz++;
            if(tablou[i][j]==e)
            {
                printf("Elementul a fost gasit la pozitia %d fata de elementul 1, pe linia %d si coloana %d",poz,i+1,j+1);
                nr++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(nr>0)
    {
        printf("\nElementul a fost gasit de %d ori",nr);
    }
}
```

I can't see what's wrong, any help would be appreciated , thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare the array after initializing `n` and `m` to non-zero values, something like this

```
int m, n;

if (scanf("%d%d", &n, &m) != 2)
{
    /* you could write a function that tries to get input again */
    printf("invalid input\n");
    return -1;
}
int tablou[m][n];
```

also not that `main()` should return `int`.

Comment: Any way i could declare or initialize the array at the start of the program ? Because my teacher does not like declarations that are not at the start. It only works if i declare and initialize after getting the non-zero values for m and n. Also it does not allow me to enter an array bigger than 2*2. Thanks.

Comment: I like your teacher! Then you need one of two solutions, this `#define N 100 #define M 100` and then `int tablou[M][N]` then ensure that `n < N` and `m < M`, or use `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

@iharob uses the new dynamc arrays of C99. It is a nice feature with the compiler doing lots of things for you. In older chainsaw versions of C you have to do that yourself:

```
int m, n, *tablou;

if (scanf("%d%d", &n, &m) != 2)
{
    printf("invalid input\n");
    return -1;
}
if ((tablou= calloc(n*m, sizeof(int)))==NULL) return -1;
...
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        poz++;
        if(tablou[ i*n + j]==e)
            ...
```